# disable meta viewport just in one div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a crop image function in my website.

the problem is, with meta viewport this image is too big and hard to crop. If I change the image size using CSS the crop cordenates will not match.

So I want to disable the viewport in this cropper div only.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Can I do something like this? or jquery...

```
#MyDIV{
@viewport {
 disable...
}
}
```

thank you friends!

Comment: if it's too big just try setting `max-width: 100%` to the image

Comment: @fcalderan oh, good try, but it, somehow, bugs my cropper...

Comment: Hi @RGS! Did you ever find a solution for this? I am trying to force a single div to use a specific viewport, different than the one applied to the site.

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested, the best solution would be to set a max-width on the image div container.
You can still use css meta tag but just to avoid users play around with the "zoom-in" functionality that can distort the image ratio. Have a look here for more clarification: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp, however you just need to set this meta tag in the document head:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Then, in your css file you set a media query like this:

```
 /** replace 480px with your target screen width **/
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  #MyDIV {
    max-width: 200px; /** replace 200px with your desired image max width **/
    margin: 0 auto; /** to center the div in the page **/
  }
}
```

Hope this would help

Comment: thank you for your answer! my problem is the crop function that when I change image size or div size it does not work well.